# Bematech MP-4200 TH esperaImpressao

Tags: c#, impressora

Boa tarde estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação que precisa ter certeza que o documento foi impresso na impressora térmica não fiscal bematech MP-4200 TH, como a impressora tem buffer mesmo que não tenha papel nela ela envia o comando pra impressora e retorna como ok, dessa forma não tenho como saber se de fato foi impresso ou se apenas enviado para impressora, verificando a classe possui uma função que segundo a documentação faz a aplicação aguardar o termino da impressão.

```
/// <summary>
/// Esta função segura a execução do Aplicativo, até que todo o texto enviado seja impresso.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="modo">INTEIRO modo de espera.</param>
/// <returns>INTEIRO - Indica se a função conseguiu enviar o comando para impressora.</returns>
[DllImport("MP2032.dll")]
public static extern int EsperaImpressao(int modo);
```

Porém isto não está funcionando retornando que isto desbalanceou a pilha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esse tipo de erro geralmente está atrelado a uma coisa conhecida como [Calling Convention](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/k2b2ssfy.aspx) e o attributo `[DllImport]` tem uma propriedade na qual você define qual deverá ser o modo utilizado para a função importada.

Quando você não especifica nenhum o C# define por padrão o [StdCall](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.callingconvention.aspx) e não deve ser como a dll que você utilza foi compilada, veja no link acima os outros valores que você pode utilizar, os tipos mais utilizados são StdCall e Cdecl.

Ficaria algo do tipo:

```
[DllImport("MP2032.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int EsperaImpressao(int modo);
```

Comment: Obrigado resolveu o problema!